# How to share validations accross models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have this validations in a model TipoMovimiento:

```
class TipoMovimiento < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_validation :default_values

  validates :codigo, :numericality => {:greater_than => 0}
  validates :codigo, :descripcion, :sintetico, :presence => true
  validates :codigo, :descripcion, :sintetico, :uniqueness => true
  validates :descripcion, :length => {:minimum => 3}
  validates :sintetico, :length => {:minimum => 2}

private
  def default_values
    self.estado ||= true if self.estado.nil?
    self.codigo ||= TipoMovimiento.maximum(:codigo) + 1
  end
end
```

Also, I have others models with the same fields, and I don't want to repeat these validations on them. How I do that?

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use [custom validations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#performing-custom-validations) or [inheritance](http://mediumexposure.com/multiple-table-inheritance-active-record/).

Answer (score 2):

What I would do is create a separate model:

```
module Validator                                                                                                                                              
  def self.included(base)
    base.send :validates, :name, :presence => true
  end
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Validator
end
```